# Get object at point? wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

Is it possible to get what object is at point (x,y) with wxpython?

```
buton=wx.Button(self, id=wx.ID_ANY, label='object',pos=(10,10), size=(175, 28))
print GetObjectAtPoint(10,10)   # this function does not exist
```

If there is anything similar to the above, that would be nice or if there is suggestions on what I should do. Or even, if there is anything such as GetObjectsInRange(x1,y1,x2,y2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is

> wx.FindWindowAtPoint(pt)

Also

> GenericFindWindowAtPoint(pt)

and

> FindWindowAtPointer()

See 
http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/

Comment: Is this compatible with panels?

Comment: FindWindowAtPoint() is a module function not a member function in wxPanel

Try
wx.FindWindowAtPoint((0,0))

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried FindWindowsAtPoint()? That's about the only thing I can think of that does something like that. You might also take a look at the Widget Inspection Tool to find out how it grabs information about widgets when you click on them.

Comment: I do not think this method works with panels? or does it? I have tried it and it returns an error, 'MyPanel' object has no attribute 'FindWindowAtPoint'